Проблема с качеством импортируемых текстур из Blender в Unity
Я создаю небольшую игру и использую для моделирования/текстурирования большинства объектов Blender. Я столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу никак решить довольно долго.
Создав модель в blender, я создаю UV-карту 1К/2К/4К размера для разных объектов (в зависимости от их "важности"). После этого я наношу на объект текстуры необходимым мне образом. После этого я запекаю эти текстуры (конкретно карты diffuse, roughness, normal) и сохраняю полученные изображения на компьютер. Далее экспортирую модель в формате .fbx в Unity. Уже там я вытаскиваю материалы из этой модели, перевожу их в autodesk и вношу полученные ранее карты. Всё работает нормально за исключением того, что текстуры выглядят банально плохо.
Blender:

Unity:

На примере стены особенно заметны ухудшения. Итак, можно ли как то исправить это? Хотя бы немного приблизиться в качеству blender?
Что я уже пробовал:

Отключил сжатие при импорте в Unity
Изменял настройки импорта на картах в Unity (переключал разрешение, billinear/point и так далее)
Пробовал улучшить визуал с помощью пост-процессинга (слабо помогло)
Отключал Mipmap и Grey Scale

Я использую URP.

Частично решено. Просто воссоздавайте необходимый материал прямо в юнити, ничего не запекая, и настраивайте его с помощью ProBuilder. Это выглядит хорошо.
